# Multiple domains on same Symfony app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

After hours of researches, I still can't find the answer but I am sure there is a way to solve it.
I have got a Symfony app that features sites of my clients.
**The routing is like : /app.php/{userId}/**
I want to create domains (not subdomains) to point to each user page, so 
domain1.com -> app.php/1/
domain2.com -> app.php/2/
etc...
But when I try to do that with Apache hosts, I get a Symfony error : "No route found for GET /". I understand why, but I cant find a solution with Apache hosts or htaccess neither with Symfony. 
I dont want to duplicate my app.php or app folder. 
Maybe the solution is in the htaccess... 
What do you think about it ?
Thank you in advance for your ideas :)

Julien

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for each hostname you can set up a virtual host that has it´s document root at your simfony app like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domainone.com
  DocumentRoot "/Projects/Project/web"
  <Directory "/Projects/Project/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domaintwo.com
  DocumentRoot "/Projects/Project/web"
  <Directory "/Projects/Project/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Like ServerAlias says 
    you could also have one VirtualHost tag with multiple hostnames as ServerAlias

```
  ServerName domainone.com
  ServerAlias domainone.com domaintwo.com
```

In your symfony routing configuration you can then parse the hostname

```
routing_one:
    resource: "@yourBundle/Resources/config/routingOne.yml"
    prefix: /customerIdOne
    host: "domainone.com"

routing_two:
    resource: "@yourBundle/Resources/config/routingTwo.yml"
    prefix: /customerIdTwo
    host: "domaintwo.com"
```

Comment: You could use just one VirtualHost and one or more [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias).

Comment: Thxxxx, it worked ! Regan Lawton told me the same on twitter. http://t.co/p5RKo9Yqwx